# One husband for two sisters in genealogy tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, genealogytree

I want to display the marriage of two sisters with the same man in a genealogy tree. I use the genealogytree package.

The following code produces the husband node twice, each having children with one of the sisters. What I intend is the husband node being placed in the middle inbetween the sisters with two edges going down to the children symmetrically just from this one husband node.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}              
\usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document} 
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \genealogytree[]{ 

        child{
            g[male]{A}
        p[female]{B} 
        child{
         g[female]{Sister 1}
         p[male]{Husband of both sisters}   
         c[male]{Son A}    
    }
    child{
    g[female]{Sister 2}
    p[male]{Husband of both sisters}
    c[male]{Son B}
    }
    }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `genealogytree` package have a `westvirginia` option to handle this?  (Just kidding!!)

Comment: I've toyed with the idea of doing a genealogy tree, but was going to use a separate page for each mated pair and link them using hyperref.

Comment: It is a good question. I have seen it happening more than once that a man marries his sister-in-law. Often after his wife deceased. Sometimes more naughty as well :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easier to get "Husband of both sisters" with two wives and children in a tree that starts with him, so you can combine a tree that starts with him with a tree that starts earlier.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}              
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  % Tree for the common husband with descendents
  \genealogytree[
  nullify edge level shift,
  ]{
    child{
      p[id=sister1,female]{Sister 1}
      c[male]{Son A}
      g[male]{Husband of both sisters}
      union{
        p[female]{Sister 2}
        c[male]{Son B}
      }
    }
  }
\genealogytree[
  set position=sister1c at sister1,
  ]{
    child{
      g[male]{A}
      p[female]{B}
      child{
        g[id=sister1c,female]{Sister 1}
      }
      child{
        p[phantom,male]{}
        % This version of sister2 is not in the exact same position
        % as the one above, so make it a phantom*
        g[phantom*,female]{Sister 2}
      }
    }
  }

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]