# How to add 2nd husband of 2nd wife and descendants to genealogytree?

Tags: genealogytree

In my family, after my father (h1) and mother (w1) divorced, my father remarried to w2. So far so good.  But in the genealogy tree I also would like to add the previous husband of w2 (w2-h2).  How do I do that?  I tried it with `union`, and you can see my attempt in the file below, but I commented it out since it gives me error when compiling.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
% h=husband
% w=wife
% w2-h1=2nd wife's 1st husband
% c=child
\begin{genealogypicture}
  child{
    g[male]{h1}
    p[female]{w1}
    union{
      p[female]{w2}
      % union{
      % p[male]{w2-h2}
      % }
      c{h1-w2's c}
    }
    c{w1-h1's  c}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer the updated question. I learned a *lot* from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517775/194703).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
% Tree for the common husband with descendents
% h=husband
% w=wife
% w2-h1=2nd wife's 1st husband
% c=child
\genealogytree{
  child{
    g[male]{h1}
    p[female]{w1}
    union{
      p[female,id=wife2]{w2}
      c{h1-w2's c}
    }
    c{w1-h1's  c}
  }
}
\genealogytree[set position=wife at wife2]{
   child{
    g[female,id=wife]{w2} 
    p[male]{w2-h2}
    }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ANSWER TO MY INTERPRETATION OF THE FIRST VERSION OF THE QUESTION**: This is more or less copied from p. 67 of the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  child{
   p[female]{w1}
   g[male]{h1}
   c{w1-h1's c}
   union{
    p[female]{w2}
    c{w2-h1's c}
   }
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can rearrange it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  child{
   g[male]{h1}
   union{
    p[female]{w1}
    c{w1-h1's c}
   }
   p[female]{w2}
   c{w2-h1's c}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It even works in extreme situations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  child{
   g[male]{Henry VIII}
   union{
    p[female]{Catherine of Aragon}
    c{Mary I}
   }
   union{
    p[female]{Anne Boleyn}
    c{Elizabeth I}
   }
   union{
    p[female]{Jane Seymour}
    c{Edward VI}
   }
   union{
    p[female]{Anne of Cleves}
   }
   union{
    p[female]{Catherine Howard}
   }
   p[female]{Catherine Parr}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question was about adding a previous (or just another) husband to w2. Adding several wives to the same husband was not a problem.  My example already accomplished that with two wives.

Comment: I see the source of confusion in my original post, so I corrected the typo.  The missing piece I cannot accomplish is `w2-h2` not `w2-h1`, which I already have.

Comment: @MátéWierdl I tried to answer the edited post.